# Include file in git repository but do not track

Tags: git, repository, config

`config.ini` exists in a git repository and should be included when cloning.  This file will be modified on a per-installation basis, however, it should not be required to commit the changes before doing a future pull and should not be replaced or modified by that pull.

`git rm --cached config.ini` and committing the changes will not work as future clones will not include this file.  I suppose can do this and add `config.ini` to `.gitignore` but then include and commit `config.example.ini` which must be locally copied to `config.ini` upon each installation if necessary, but this seems clunky.

On the local machines, I can use `git update-index --assume-unchanged config.ini`, however, this needs to be performed for each installation and is not ideal.

What is the best approach to include a file in git repository but not to track or modify it upon future pull requests?

Comment: AFAIK, once a file is in a Git repo, it's open season for someone to modify it.  Even if you setup safeguards, they could probably easily be undone.  So, you should decide whether or not this file really belongs in the repo.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen  They SHOULD be able to modify it.  I just do not wish their modifications to be undone if they use pull to update the other content.

Comment: Pull doesn’t undo anything.

Comment: @evolutionxbox  If `config.ini` was in the repository, wouldn't `git pull origin master` download it (or complain if the local copy was different)?

Comment: It would complain you’ve not committed the change. The example “clunky” workaround is the current best plan. As git isn’t designed for per machine set config.

Comment: @evolutionxbox  Sounds good.  Thank you

Comment: You're welcome. Sorry for the bad tone.